# función muy sencilla en R no encuentra el objeto de entrada

Tags: r, funciones

Estoy empezando en esto de R y haciendo una función que es lo más tonto del mundo pero obtengo un resultado inesperado.

Instalé el paquete caRtociudad para obtener información sobre direcciones:

```
https://github.com/cjgb/caRtociudad
```

Algo tan sencillo como esto funciona de lujo:

```
> cartociudad_geocode("Calle Alcalá 145, Madrid", max_results = 1)

  priority status              comments province municipality road_type road_name     road_fid numpk_name   zip    numpk_fid
1        1      1 Portal/Pk encontrado.   Madrid       Madrid     CALLE    ALCALA 280790007456        145 28009 280790134225
  longitude latitude
1    -3.677    40.42
```

Sin embargo si lo meto en una función porque quiero luego hacer cosas con el resultado, que no me gusta cómo lo devuelve:

```
obtener_datos <- function(direccion){
    caRtociudad::cartociudad_geocode(direccion, max_results = 1)
}
```

Devuelve un error:

```
obtener_datos("Calle Alcalá 145, Madrid")

 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object direccion not found
```

Incluso si lo meto a fuego en la función, me devuelve el error:

```
obtener_datos <- function(direccion){
    direccion <- "Calle Alcalá 145, Madrid" 
    caRtociudad::cartociudad_geocode(direccion, max_results = 1)
}

 Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object direccion not found
```

Estoy un poco perdido, la verdad, porque esto debería ser lo más sencillo del mundo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es tuyo sino que está en la función `cartociudad_geocode`, al principio de la misma se está haciendo `api.args <- lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], eval)` entiendo que para obtener todos los parámetros con los que se invocó la función y armar el objeto `api.args` con los mismos, el problema es que `match.call()` en función de como se invoque va a devolver valores distintos.

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
fntTest <- function(param_original) {
    print(as.list(match.call())[-1])
}

fntTest2 <- function(param_wrapper) {
    fntTest(param)
}
```

Una es una función base y la otra es un wrapper a la anterior, veamos como resuelven los parámetros recibidos

```
> test <- "prueba"
> # 1. Valor fijo
> fntTest("Prueba")
$param_original
[1] "Prueba"

> # 2. Variable
> fntTest(test)
$param_original
test

> # 3. Valor fijo
> fntTest2("Prueba")
$param_original
param

> # 4. Variable
> fntTest2(test)
$param_original
param
```

Con esto vemos que en el caso 1 se obtuvo el valor recibido, en el caso 2 el nombre del objeto que le estamos pasando a la función, pero cuando usamos la función "wrapper" solo podemos resolver el nombre del parámetro de `fntTest2 <- function(param)`, este justamente es el problema ya que no obtuvimos ni el valor ni el objeto que contiene el dato, obtuvimos el nombre del parámetro de la función "wrapper", por eso básicamente `cartociudad_geocode` falla al hacer esto:

```
lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], eval)
```

Resumiendo, es un bug de la función, un modo de solucionar fácil el tema es reescribir el tratamiento de lo parámetros en `cartociudad_geocode` de la siguiente forma:

```
api.args<-list()
if(!is.null(full_address))
    api.args$full_address <- full_address
# y así con cada uno
```

Comment: Algo me imaginaba, porque había programado cosas similares con anterioridad y no podía entender porqué algo tan tonto fallase. Gracias Patricio